# Approximating $\zeta^{(r)}(s)$ by a sum

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Let $\eta:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be compactly supported, continuous and piecewise $C^1$, with its derivative $\eta'$ being of bounded variation. It is completely unsurprising that one can prove (using Euler-Maclaurin) that, for any $r\geq 0$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\geq \max(|t|,c)$,
$$\zeta^{(r)}(1+it) = (-1)^r \sum_n (\log n)^r \eta\left(\frac{n}{x}\right) n^{-1-it} + O^*\left(\frac{\kappa_0}{t^2} + \frac{\kappa_1}{x}\right) \log^r x,$$ where $c$, $\kappa_0$ and $\kappa_1$ are explicit constants depending only on $\eta$ and $r$, and $O^*(A)$ means "a quantity whose absolute value is $\leq A$". In particular, a non-explicit version of the case $r=0$ can be found in standard textbooks.

At the same time, the proof my collaborator and I have had to write up is three pages long, and that makes me think that we may be being silly. Can an explicit estimate of the above form be found in the literature? Alternatively - is there a clearly shorter derivation (with reasonably good values of $c$, $\kappa_0$ and $\kappa_1$ that can be made explicit)?

EDIT: What we do is to first derive a formula of type
$$\zeta^{(r)}(s) = (-1)^r \left(\sum_{n\leq x} (\log n)^r n^{-s} - F_{r,s}(x)\right) + O^*\left(\frac{C}{x}\right) (\log x)^r$$
(for $r<x \log x$) by means of Euler-Maclaurin in the usual way. Here $F_{r,s}(t)$ is the antiderivative of $(\log t)^r t^{-s}$ tending to $0$ as $t\to \infty$.

Then we use that formula to derive a similar formula with a smooth truncation by $\eta(n/x)$ instead of a sharp truncation $n\leq x$. This is very short and easy, but you can see it is already a little indirect. (Somehow I end up getting something more complicated as a whole if I apply Euler-Maclaurin directly.)

Then we show that $$\int_1^\infty F_{r,s}(u x) \eta'(u) du$$ is $O(1/t^2)$ (with an explicit implied constant depending on $f$). It is here that we use the assumptions that $f$ is piecewise $C^1$ and $f'$ has bounded variation: after an initial step, the proof consists just of two instances of integration by parts. (Things are nicer here if one assumes that $\eta(t)=1$ for all $t$ in some interval $[0,\delta]$, but I'm not sure that that's strictly needed.)

As you can see, this is all rather roundabout. Surely there has to be an easier way and/or a very well-known way in the literature, at least for $r=0$?

Comment: Does your definition of $O^*$ have a flipped inequality than what it should be?

Comment: Oops, yes, fixed.